# How to build nested list from jquery :header selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nested

My html looks like this:

`<h1 id="header1">H1</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="header2">H2</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <h2 id="header3">H2</h2>
      <p>lorem upsum</p>
       <h3 id="subHeader1">H3</h3>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>`

I am using the following jquery selector to get all the headings that have an id.

```
var headings = $( ":header[id]" );
```

I want to build an nested list of all the headings so that I come up with this:

```
<ul><li>H1
     <ul><li>H2<li>
         <li>H2
           <ul><li>H3</li></ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
 </li></ul>
```

I was hoping there was an easy way of accomplishing this.  Searched stackoverflow but was not able to find anything.  I am able to build a flat list but having trouble building the nested list.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to say that this is not really easy. It does not just require some algorithm but also some knowledge about jQuery, it's a combination of the two, so it affects how we code it.

The idea here is you need to initialize a root `ul`, in each `ul` we should save some reference to the collection of the child headers, then we need to loop through this collection to turn each header to a `ul`. The newly converted `ul` should be added to some collection (some kind of stack) and we have a `while` loop running until this stack becomes empty.

It's hard to explain it better because as I said, this is fairly complicated especially to newbies who are new to both algorithm and jQuery. Here is the code:

```
//Initialize the root UL
var ul = $('<ul>');
for(var i = 1; i < 8; i++){
  var hs = $('h' + i);
  if(hs.length){
    ul[0].childHeaders = hs
    ul[0].childHeaderLevel = i;
    break;
  }
}

var rootUl = ul;
//main loop
while(ul.length){    
  var nextUl = $();
  //loop through each ul
  ul.each(function(){
     var innerUl = this;
     var n = this.childHeaderLevel;
     //turn each childHeader into the corresponding ul
     innerUl.childHeaders.each(function(i,elem){
        var childUl = $('<ul>').append('<li>' + $(elem).html() + '</li>')
                               .appendTo(innerUl);
        childUl[0].childHeaders = $(this).nextUntil('h' + n)
                                         .filter('h' + (n+1));
        childUl[0].childHeaderLevel = n + 1;            
        nextUl = nextUl.add(childUl);
     });                            
  });
  ul = nextUl;   
}
//append the root UL to the body after emptying
$('body').empty().append(rootUl);
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/V9FdK/1/)